# Problem in setting layout

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout, border-layout

I have made a `JFrame` and inside that frame, there is panel on which I have placed various containers using `GridBagLayout`.  I have set layout of `JFrame` to be `BorderLayout`, and added panel in `BorderLayout.WEST`.  I want to show that panel's containers at the top left corner.  How can I do that?

Even if I try to add panel to `BorderLayout.NORTH` then also it is displayed in top center but instead **I want to be in top left corner**.

Is there any way to do that? I.E. any other layout I should use as I want to show

```
label1
button1     button2     button3

label2
button1     button2     button3

label 3
button1     button2     button3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy to do with just `GridLayout` and `BorderLayout`.

[image: Label-Button Layout]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class LabelButtonLayout {

    public static Component getButtonLayout(int num) {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));

        p.add(new JLabel("Label " + num), BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel b = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0,25,5));
        for (int ii=1; ii<4; ii++) {
            b.add(new JButton("Button " + ii));
        }
        p.add(b, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return p;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,3,15));
                for (int ii=1; ii<4; ii++) {
                    gui.add(getButtonLayout(ii));
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this, one being to further nest JPanels. Place a JPanel BorderLayout.NORTH, and give it a BorderLayout. Then add your other JPanel to this one, BorderLayout.WEST.

Comment: For a `JLabel` it is not necessary to add the constraining 'left' panel.  See my example.  +1 for nested layout, though.

Comment: @Geetanjali  If I understand your question (and I'm not sure I do understand it), my example demonstrates.  Note that there is no `NestedLayout` class as such.  A nested layout is just about combining different layouts to achieve an effect that would be difficult to achieve using any other single layout.

Comment: @Andrew:ya sir I knw but i m able to add nested Jpanel in a Jframe.

Comment: It is easy to add a nested JPanel to anything that it needs to appear in.  It does not matter if that is a `JOptionPane`/`JDialog`, a `JFrame`, `JWindow` or `JApplet`, one side of a `JSplitPane`, another `JPanel` etc.  If you cannot figure how to do it, I suggest you ask another question specific to that, and showing your best effort in a [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  And as a personal request, please don't call me 'sir'.  If it is necessary to refer to me specifically, 'Andrew' is fine.

Comment: To nest JPanels, you simply create a JPanel and add it into another.

Comment: @Hovercraft:I have used but didn't succeed.I have to add new jpanel to get added to the previous panel???

Answer (score 0):

Border layout does not allow you to add something to NORTHWEST directly.

You might want to make the layout of the `JFrame` to `GridBagLayout`, so that you have the flexibility you want

Comment: ya I have used gridbag layout in Jpanel to set the containers as I have already mentioned it

Comment: Yes. But you may want to make the `JFrame`, which is in `BorderLayout` now, to itself `GridBagLayout`.

Comment: hey can we set two gridbag layout in it

Comment: but anything i set in grid bag layout will itself cum in center.so both gridx=0 and gridy=0 overlap

Comment: If `GridBagLayout` is the answer, it must have been a silly question (most of the time).